# Trouble Adding Legend to Multiple geom_density layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know similar questions have been asked, but trying the solutions to those hasn't seemed to work for me so far.

I have the following:

```
ggplot(music2) +
  geom_density(aes(x = danceability), color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_density(aes(x = energy), color = "purple", fill = "purple", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_density(aes(x = valence), color = "green", fill = "green", alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(title = "Attributes of Top 20 Spotify Hits",
       x = "Amount of Attribute",
       y = "Frequency")
```

which gives me

[image]

I would like a legend with each variable by color. I had tried adding the following to the end:

```
 + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "purple" , "green"), 
                      labels = c("Dance", "Energy", "Valence"))
```

but that did not add anything different. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: try adding `breaks = c("danceability", "energy", "valence")` to the `scale_color_manual` call.

Comment: That sadly still doesn't work

Comment: Try adding the `color` and `fill` of the geoms inside the `aes()` call, then use both `scale_color_manual()` for the lines and `scale_fill_manual()` for the areas.

Comment: Thank you teunbrand, than worked!